# Does Wildfly 10.0.0 final Version support OCSP like Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, wildfly-10, ocsp

Please guide me about wildfly 10.0.0 version. I want to know that wildfly 10.0.0 version is still using tomcat internally to deploy war applications or not. I want to enable OCSP stapling for my server which is using same version of wildfly . Can you please guide me about these information and guide me if it can be enable on this version and how it will be. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Wildfly uses Undertow.

Comment: hello @ErnestKiwele can you please guide me that how can i enable ocsp stapling in wildfly perhaps in undertow that you told.

Comment: @NikhilMehta This [unresolved Wildfly bug report ELY-434 titled "OCSP Support"](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ELY-434) suggests that Wildlfy does not currently support OCSP stapling. Do you have a link to confirm that it does?

Comment: @skomisa thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

WildFly has not used Tomcat internally since about the time its name was changed from JBoss AS to WildFly (i.e. JBoss AS 7.x -> WildFly 8.x). It now uses an implementation of the servlet API called Undertow.

WildFly support for OCSP was documented at [SSL Configuration using Elytron Subsystem](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/SSL+Configuration+using+Elytron+Subsystem) under the heading "Using Online Certificate Status Protocol".

This would emcompass WildFly 14.0 or newer, which was released shortly after this.